# Validate a simple time date format ? (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss)

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm going to validate a simple time date format (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`) as follows. This implementation works for most major validations but somehow I found some validations doesn't seems to be working.
such as if you enter `2014-09-11T03:27:54kanmsdklnasd` , `2014-09-11T03:27:54234243` it doesn't validate. Can you please point out my code error?

**code**

```
String timestamp = "2014-09-11T03:27:54";
SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
try{
    format.parse(timestamp);
    LOG.info("Timestamp is a valid format");
}
catch(ParseException e)
{
    return ssoResponse;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `format.setLenient(false);`?

Comment: Yup but it didn't work for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat.parse()` (which comes from `DateFormat.parse()`) cannot be used for full-string validation because quoting from its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-):

> The method **may not use the entire text** of the given string.

Instead you can use the [`DateFormat.parse(String source, ParsePosition pos)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) to validate.

The `ParsePosition` you pass is an "in-out" parameter, you can get info out of it after you call the `parse()` method:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
// If you set lenient to false, ranges will be checked, e.g.
// seconds must be in the range of 0..59 inclusive.
format.setLenient(false);

String timestamp = "2014-09-11T03:27:54";
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);

format.parse(timestamp, pos); // No declared exception, no need try-catch

if (pos.getErrorIndex() >= 0) {
    System.out.println("Input timestamp is invalid!");
} else if (pos.getIndex() != timestamp.length()) {
    System.out.println("Date parsed but not all input characters used!"
         + " Decide if it's good or bad for you!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Input is valid, parsed completely.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still im struggling with validating '2014-09-11T03:27:54kanmsd' .

Comment: My solution will find that `pos.getIndex() != timestamp.length()`, you can treat that as an error if you want to.

Comment: but it skips pos.getIndex() != timestamp.length() for this validation (2014-09-11T03:27:54kanmsd) ..other one (2014-09-11T03:27:54234243) is validated and ok.

Comment: For `2014-09-11T03:27:54kanmsd` the code says "not all input chars used". The other will be "Invalid" if you set `format.setLenient(false)`. I edited the code a few times, I think you use an older version.

Answer (score 1):

*Using JodaTime it is very Easy*.

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

//from your method
String inputDateString = "2014-09-11T03:27:54kanmsdklnasd";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
boolean isValid = isValidDateFormat(inputDateString, pattern);

private boolean isValidDateFormat(String inputDateString, String format){
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
        dtf.parseDateTime(inputDateString);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

You will get..
 *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 Invalid format: "2014-09-11T03:27:54kanmsdklnasd" is malformed at "kanmsdklnasd"*
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, check the following notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stream.of(
                "2014-09-11T03:27:54",
                "2014-09-11T03:27:54kanmsdklnasd",
                "2014-09-11T03:27:54234243"
        ).forEach(s -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s));
            }catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.out.printf("The date-time string, \"%s\" is not valid.%n", s);
            }
        });;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-09-11T03:27:54
The date-time string, "2014-09-11T03:27:54kanmsdklnasd" is not valid.
The date-time string, "2014-09-11T03:27:54234243" is not valid.
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>